# RadioButton to string, string to array

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I tried that way

```
string value;
if(radioButton1.Checked)
{
value = "1";
}
```

But when I wanted to use value variable to push it to array, error appeared. It was because value wasn't declared in this scope. It's my fault, since I totally forgot about get/set metods. I tried something like this:(I could probably use boolean thou)

```
string[] value = new string[] { value };
```

And it didn't worked. So my question is: how or what's the easiest way to put information about radiobox (If it's checked or not) in array?

edit: Sure. That's how I tried to make it work. Also tried to change value from string to int and convert it afterwards, but without luck. It's whole code for this button. My plan was to check which radiobox was selected and then convert it to array and store in .txt file.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        bool value;
        if (radioButton1.Checked)
        {
            value = true;
        }
        else if (radioButton2.Checked)
        {
            value = false;
        }

        string[] radiobox = new string[] { value };
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\test.txt", radiobox);
        }
```

another edit:
So after I changed string to boolean, I'm getting this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'string'
```

And when I'm trying to convert it to string (Because array doesn't want to accept bool)

```
string[] radiobox = new string[] { value.ToString() };
```

I'm getting another error:

```
Use of unassigned local variable 'value'
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. please post more complete code.

Comment: You're using the same identifier for the array and string, (they are both called value).

Comment: `string[] value = new string[] { value };` This makes NO sense. You make an array, but only for 1 value, and make the value in the array the array itself. I doubt that will even compile.

Comment: The `.Checked` value for a radioButton is a boolean.  Are you wanting to store the true/false of that boolean, or just the '1' you mention above?

Comment: More code please... I'm very, very confused.

Comment: All I need is information about the button, which one is checked, so boolean will do fine. I'll take care of that and will edit source code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Lists instead of arrays? I find them easier to work with. Also, if you're only interested in whether the radiobox is checked, your value could simply be a Boolean.

Comment: This would have been better served as a comment, instead of an answer.  If you are going to answer a question, you really should give code to back up what you are saying.